# How to get payment method and shipping method in grid view magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I want to show payment method and shipping method along with other attributes here is my grid view code

```
<?php
    class Mb_Orderprocessing_Block_Adminhtml_Wholesales_Grid extends
        Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId('id');
            $this->setDefaultSort('name');
            $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);

            $this->setUseAjax(true);
        }
        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
            $this->setCollection($collection);

            parent::_prepareCollection();
            return $this;
        }
        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
            $helper = Mage::helper('maxoptra');

            $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Order #'),
                'index'  => 'increment_id',
                'type'   => 'text',
            ));
            $this->addColumn('expected_delivery', array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Delivery Date'),
                'index'  => 'expected_delivery',
                'type'   => 'text',
            ));
            $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Method'),
                'index'  => 'shipping_method',
                'type'   => 'text',
            ));
            $this->addColumn('status', array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Status'),
                'index'  => 'status',
                'type'   => 'text',
            ));

            $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Paid'),
                'index'  => 'base_grand_total',
                'type'   => 'text',
            ));
        //here i want to show these 2 attributes also how can i get them

            return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }

        public function getGridUrl()
        {
            return $this->getUrl('*/*/orderstatusgrid', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the payment and shipping method in your collection before showing them into the Grid.

> Adding Payment and Shipping in the collection

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
 $collection->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id','method');

$this->setCollection($collection);
```

> Adding columns in the order grid

```
//adding Payment method column in the grid
$this->addColumn('method', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
    'index' => 'method',
    'type'=> 'options',
    'options' => $this->getPaymentList(),
));

//adding Shipping method column in the grid
$this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Method'),
        'index'  => 'shipping_method',
        'type'   => 'text',
    ));
```

> Get payment list function for the shipping method column

```
public function getPaymentList()
{
    $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
    $methods = array();
    foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel)
    {
        $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title', 1);
        if(empty($paymentTitle)) {
            $paymentTitle = Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance($paymentCode)->getTitle();
        }
        $methods[$paymentCode] = $paymentTitle;
    }
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: thanks for the help but i had to change $collection with this table that why i edit you answer